# SQL inner join incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, wordnet

My issue is the following:

I'm trying my hand at WordNet MySQL, trying to add another view aside from the ones already present, like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW synsetsXsemlinksXsynsets AS 
SELECT 
       linkid,s.synsetid AS ssynsetid
       ,s.definition AS sdefinition
       ,d.synsetid AS dsynsetid
       ,d.definition AS ddefinition 
FROM synsets AS s 
     INNER JOIN 
     semlinks AS l ON s.synsetid = l.synset1id 
     INNER JOIN 
     synsets AS d ON l.synset2id = d.synsetid;
```

So taking that code as a reference I tried to do something like:

```
CREATE VIEW graph AS  
SELECT 
       l.linkid
       ,s.synsetid AS sssinsetid
       ,w.lemma AS swlemma
       ,s.definition AS sdefinition
       ,d.synsetid AS dsynsetid
       ,w.lemma AS dwlemma
       ,d.definition AS ddefinition 
FROM synsets AS s 
     INNER JOIN  
     semlinks AS l ON s.synsetid = l.synset1id 
     INNER JOIN  
     synsets AS d ON l.synset2id = d.synsetid 
     INNER JOIN  
     lexlinks AS x ON l.synset1id = x.synset1id 
                      AND l.synset2id = x.synset2id 
     INNER JOIN  
     words AS w ON w.wordid = x.word1id 
                      AND x.word2id = w.wordid
```

In order to get: `linkid | ssynsetid | swlemma | sdefition| dsynsetid | dwlemma | ddefition`.

But it did not worked as expected. While the first gives me 285639 rows, mine just give me 12 rows. I'm not sure where is the problem. Any help?

EDIT:

What I expected to happen was that the statement will return the words in sslemma and their lemmas in dwlemma. So I was hopping I will get the words used and their lemma form also. Thanks.

Comment: Why should they be the same you have 2 additional joins in your second query?

Comment: That is the output for that input because that's how SQL works. What other answer do you expect? How SQL & its subexpressions work are duplicate questions anyway & easily answered by any (authoritative) intro to SQL. If you want to know why your (wrong) expectations are not met then you have to tell us your expectations. What are they, exactly enough that we can tell you where they are wrong? What is the first subexpression evaluated that doesn't return what you expect?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @P.Salmon No, I was not expecting to be exactly the same but I was expecting to get more than 12 entries, I think those 12 entries are the ones where the lemma and the word are equal. So I need to change the consult. philipxy I will try to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: Your edit does not help. You are not clear. Nobody could take what you wrote & know what your query is supposed to do or why you think it would do that. (Of course, we can guess.) Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now. Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear.

Comment: I will try again, being more clear. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN for the 2 extra tables.

```
 ...
 FROM synsets AS s 
 INNER JOIN  
 semlinks AS l ON s.synsetid = l.synset1id 
 INNER JOIN  
 synsets AS d ON l.synset2id = d.synsetid 
 LEFT JOIN  
 lexlinks AS x ON l.synset1id = x.synset1id 
                  AND l.synset2id = x.synset2id 
 LEFT JOIN  
 words AS w ON w.wordid = x.word1id 
                  AND x.word2id = w.wordid
```

Because if INNER JOIN is used then it would filter those that don't match.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. But my issue is now that I get nulls where I was expecting to have something like word used and the its lemma. But your answer worked, I have to change the code maybe

Comment: Well, only you can see what data you're dealing with. :)  With only SQL as info it's hard to guess.  Maybe those AND's in those joins should be OR's?  F.e. `ON (l.synset1id = x.synset1id OR l.synset2id = x.synset2id)`